# Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index

Tags: php

Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чем может быть причина следующих ошибок:

> Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 11
>
> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare addcompetition_ref() (previously declared in W:\domains\click-bux.ru\competition_ref_fun.php:2)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Первая - обращение к несуществующей строке результата запроса.
Вторая - нельзя переопределить функцию `addcompetition_ref()`, она ранее объявлена была в `W:\domains\click-bux.ru\competition_ref_fun.php` на 2-ой строке.

Два замечания:

1. Переходи на `PDO`, `mysql_*` вырежут, если уже это не сделали.
2. Учи английский, хотя бы до уровня прочтения ошибок.